# Adding image into an ngRepeat ruins scroll glue / scroll at bottom of DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am ngRepeating over some variables, and I was originally using  ['scroll glue'](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue)  which was working fine to keep the scroll bar glued to the bottom of the div, even when a new message was added. I also tried using vanilla JavaScript which worked **until I added an image**. I have no idea why, but adding in the image makes it so the scroll starts right in the middle of the div rather than staying at the bottom.

Here is my html which works until I add the `<img>` line:

```
<div scroll-glue id="testing">

  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="message in messages"> 

        {{message.content}} 
        DATE: {{message.date}} 
        SENDER: {{message.sender.firstName}}

        <span>
          <img class="messageImage" src="{{message.sender.image}}" alt="">
        </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.messageImage {
  width: 100px;
}

#testing {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And when the Scroll Glue wasn't working,
I tried this JavaScript which still didn't work:

```
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('testing');
    console.log('this is objDiv', objDiv);
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

I am stumped! When I comment out the image, the scroll will stick to the bottom as intended. Add it back in and it seems to start in the middle of the scroll.

Comment: Hello, care to show us an image, or better, a jsfiddle so we can see the problem at work?

Comment: @AvAvt sure. I'll spin one up in just 20 minutes or so. Thanks!

Comment: @AvAvt here's the fiddle. strangely this is working as intended :/ [ http://jsfiddle.net/lukeschunk/E6aMZ/49/embedded/result/ ] so I'm more stumped now

Comment: *Very* strange indeed. The plugin is working great [no matter how I try to break it](http://jsfiddle.net/E6aMZ/56/). Looks like I can't help since I can't even figure out how to cause the problem. Sorry man.

Comment: no worries I feel dumb now - it must be something obscure in my CSS or Dom structure is all I can think of